# Unable to connect to band via ConnectAsync while it is in sleep mode

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm writing an app to collect additional sensor data while sleeping. However, as a band user I consistently use sleep mode and I have found that while the band is in sleep mode ConnectAsync fails with a BandIOException ("Failed to connect to the target band."). I only see this issue with sleep - not with run or workout activities.

Is there a way to programmatically allow access to the band while sleeping (perhaps through user consent) or do I have to choose between collecting data for my app and running sleep mode? I can imagine that there would be many apps that would like to enhance sleep mode or at least complement it, but wouldn't want to compete given all the insights that come along with sleep mode.

Thanks in advance for any information - I've looked through the samples, the documentation, and this forum without finding any indication of this issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

during sleep mode, the band does not allow for any BT activity. This is not a limitation enforced by the SDK. It is something that the band does.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

To clarify - there is no way to gather additional sensor information from the band during sleep mode because the only way to gather data is real time through BT and that can't be done in sleep mode?

It's not what I was hoping to hear but I'm glad to know for sure so I can move on from my project. I'll post on the user voice requesting the ability to extend/enhance sleep mode.  Thanks!